# Access to account, contact and opportunity on lead conversion

Tags: sharing, lead-conversion, role-hierarchy, public-group, sales-cloud

I was practicing for Sales Cloud and came across the following dummy question:

> Joe is the record owner of a Lead. A Lead sharing rule has been
>   defined so that leads owned by Joe are shared with public group called
>   ‘Joe’s Team’.When the Lead is converted to an Account, Contact, and
>   Opportunity, who will have access to these records assuming that a
>   private sharing model in place on these objects and there are no
>   sharing rules defined for these objects?
>
> a.    Joe, all members of the public group, Joe’s Team, and anyone above
>   any group member in the role hierarchy will be able to access the
>   three records.
>
> b.    Joe and anyone above him in the role hierarchy will be able to
>   access the three records
>
> c.    Joe, all members of the public group, and Joe’s Team will be able
>   to access the three records
>
> d.    Joe will be the only person who will be able to access the Account,
>   Contact, and opportunity records.

Now, according to my understanding members of the public group would not have access to the Account Contact and Opportunity records so a and c is discarded.

Option b is applicable only when sharing using role hierarchy checkbox is checked - which is not mentioned in the question at all.

So, I think the answer should be option d.

Can anyone please validate if my thought process is correct or if there is anything else that I need to consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently disable Grant Access Using Hierarchy for standard objects, so the correct answer is "b." If, at some point in the future, this changes, then "d" would become a possibility, but the question would require that that it explicitly calls out if Grant Access Using Hierarchies is enabled or not.